# How do I access member variables from one class into other using friend functions in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, friend, friend-function

I am using fried functions for the very time and was assigned to complete an incomplete code using friend functions as below.

```
//CODE GIVEN IN THE QUESTION NOT MEANT TO BE EDITED
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class store_keeper;
class item
{
    char prod_name[30];
    char prod_code[10];
    float prod_price;
    int stock_In_Hand;
    public:
    void get();
    void print()const;
    friend class store_keeper;
};
class store
{
    int num_Of_Items;
    item items[20];
    public:
    void get_details();
    void print_details() const;
    friend class store_keeper;
};
class store_keeper
{
    char name[30];
    char id[10];
    public:
    void get();
    void print();
    void stock_mgmt(store &);
};
//MY CODE
void item::get()
{
cin>>prod_name>>prod_code>>prod_price>>stock_In_Hand;
}
void item::print() const
{
    cout<<prod_name<<prod_code<<prod_price<<stock_In_Hand;
}
void store::get_details()
{
    cin>>num_Of_Items;
    for(int i=0;i<num_Of_Items;i++)
    {
        items[i].get();
    }

}
void store::print_details() const
{
    for(int j=0;j<num_Of_Items;j++)
    {
        items[j].print();
    }

}
void store_keeper::stock_mgmt(store &s)
{
    for(int k=0;k<s.num_Of_Items;k++)
    {
        if(items[k].stock_In_Hand<10)
        {
            s.print_details();
        }
    }
}
//CODE GIVEN IN THE QUESTION NOT MEANT TO BE EDITED
main()
{
    store s;
    store_keeper sk;
    s.get_details();
    sk.stock_mgmt(s);
}
```

I had to display the details of the item for which the stock in hand is less than 10.I am getting an error that num_Of_Items was not declared in this scope and suggest any edits if any required.Thanks.

Comment: You need an *instance*, an *object* to be able to access the objects member variables. In the `stock_mgmt` function you don't have any `store` object.

Comment: So, I will need to do correct store_keeper::num_Of_Items to store::num_Of _Items

Comment: In the `stock_mgmt` function you need a named argument. Then use the argument as the object.

Comment: Thanks man that worked.

Comment: But how do I use stock_In_Hand variable from the item class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems with your code, and they are all located in this function:

```
void store_keeper::stock_mgmt(store &s)
                                     ^ ~~~~~~ 1
{
    for(int k=0;k<s.num_Of_Items;k++)
    {             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 2 
        if(s.items[k].stock_In_Hand<10)
        {  ^^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 3
            s.items[k].print();
        }   ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 4
    }
}
```

1 - you need to give name to this parameter as it is needed inside your function

2 - when compiler see `store_keeper::num_Of_Items` it thinks you want to access a static variable of name `num_Of_Items` inside `store_keeper` class, but there is no such variable. What you want here is to use `s.` to read `num_Of_Items` from `s` which is of type `store`. You have befriended `store_keeper` with `store` so this is legal

3 and 4 - `items` is a field in `store` class, which is provided to your function as a parameter `s`, so use `s.` to access it.

And finally `item` has a `print` and not `print_details`

This will allow your code to compile, but probably more work is needed to make it work as expected.

Comment: Thanks very much..It worked!! And I have made the necessary edits